# Visual C++ 2013 -- _tzname and _timezone

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2013

I have a C++ Date/Time library that I have literally used for decades.  It's been rock solid without any issues.  But today, as I was making some small enhancements, my test code started complaining violently.  This following program demonstrates the problem :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>

void main(void) {
   _tzset();
   std::cout << "_tzname[ 0 ]=" << _tzname[ 0 ] << std::endl;
   std::cout << "_tzname[ 1 ]=" << _tzname[ 1 ] << std::endl;
   std::cout << "_timezone=" << _timezone << std::endl;

   size_t ret;
   char buf[ 64 ];

   _get_tzname(&ret,buf,64,0);
   std::cout << "_get_tzname[ 0 ]=" << buf << std::endl;
   _get_tzname(&ret,buf,64,1);
   std::cout << "_get_tzname[ 1 ]=" << buf << std::endl;
}
```

If I run this in the Visual Studio Debugger I get the following output :

```
_tzname[ 0 ]=SE Asia Standard Time
_tzname[ 1 ]=SE Asia Daylight Time
_timezone=-25200
_get_tzname[ 0 ]=SE Asia Standard Time
_get_tzname[ 1 ]=SE Asia Daylight Time
```

This is correct.

But if I run the program from the command line I get the following output :

```
_tzname[ 0 ]=Asi
_tzname[ 1 ]=a/B
_timezone=0
_get_tzname[ 0 ]=Asi
_get_tzname[ 1 ]=a/B
```

Note that the TZ environment variable is set to : Asia/Bangkok, which is a synonym for SE Asia Standard Time or UTC+7.  You will notice in the command line output that the tzname[ 0 ] value is the first 3 characters of Asia/Bangkok and tzname[ 1 ] is the next 3 characters.  I have some thoughts on this, but I cannot make sense of it, so I'll just stick to the facts.

Note that I included the calls to _get_tzname(...) to demonstrate that I am not getting caught in some kind deprecation trap given that _tzname and _timezone are deprecated.

I'm on Windows 7 Professional and I am linking statically to the runtime library (Multi-threaded Debug (/MTd)).  I recently installed Visual Studio 2015 and while I am not using it yet, I compiled this program there and the results are the same.  I thought there was a chance that I was somehow linking with the VS2015 libraries but I cannot verify this.  The Platform Toolset setting in both projects reflects what I would expect.

Thank you for taking the time to look at this...

Comment: When you run from the command line, are you using the same .exe that you built for the debugger or did you recompile it?

Comment: Hard to guess how this could have ever worked before.  This has been deprecated for as long as I can remember.  I certainly have no trouble getting a repro in the debug build.  Use the posix guidance on setting the TZ environment variable, it needs to be a three letter timezone name with a UTC offset.  Bangkok is "ICT+7".  No daylight savings when I try it, must be good.

Comment: @Mark.  Yes, same EXE.